# ANDROID: Lifecycle not working properly when clicking notification from lockscreen

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-lifecycle

When We Click on LockScreen Notification, This lifecycle gets triggered.

```
2020-05-20 19:19:09.983 4091-4091/com.android.wikipediaassignment D/BANANA: onResume
2020-05-20 19:19:10.032 4091-4091/com.android.wikipediaassignment D/BANANA: onPause
2020-05-20 19:19:10.099 4091-4091/com.android.wikipediaassignment D/BANANA: onStop
2020-05-20 19:19:11.859 4091-4091/com.android.wikipediaassignment D/BANANA: onStart
2020-05-20 19:19:11.863 4091-4091/com.android.wikipediaassignment D/BANANA: onResume
```

as far as I know, only onStart and onResume must be triggered.

```
private void func2() {
        Intent intent = prepareLaunchIntent3(getContext());
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Notification n = new Notification.Builder(getContext(), "789798789").setOngoing(true).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.go_icon).setAutoCancel(false)

                .setContentTitle("2").setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("789798789", "gf", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("d");
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        notificationManager.notify(11355,n);
    }
```

Comment: There is a 4 second gap between your first `onResume` and the `onPause` after it. What happens in that time?

Comment: I am really sorry. I pasted wrong logs, they are instant by the way. edited the Question as well. Thanks you can make a sample app and observe this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common. When the phone is unlocked and your app is in front you will often get a barrage of calls (often more than one) to `onResume(), onPause(), onStop()` and `onStart()`. Your app should be able to handle this.

Comment: How can someone differentiate that call. The issue is flickering UI